# Output of this C code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int *pi,*pj;
    pi=&i;
    pj=&j;

    printf("pi-pj=%d\n",pi-pj);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code on different compilers, but each time I am getting the same result, can anybody please help me understand why it is the same?

Ouput:

```
pi -pj = 3
```

I am confused, as the memory normally would be contiguously allocated. So, if let's say, our system stack is growing downwards and we have `&i = 0xA`, then the address of `j(&j) = 0x6` (since integers are 4 bytes).  Now as we are printing the difference between these two `int` pointer values, output should be `"1"`. But it is coming as `"3"`.   Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What output are you getting?  What did you expect?  If you're more precise about what this question is about, we can offer better feedback.  Also, is this a homework question?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Getting the same result from different compilers is a problem. Damn! All my programs don't work correctly then.

Comment: Sorry, for the inconvienience caused, i have edited my query, thanks for arguing on the problem description.

Comment: @Learner. Thanks for taking the time to improve your question. I don't think it's going to help much now though. A question that was closed 12 hours ago will have moved way down the pile and I doubt will get many views. I'm not sure what to advise as I'm not sure what the etiquette is for a post you want reopened, whether you should flag it with a message that says "I've tried to improve my question could it please be reopened" or something, or whether you should just start a new one and delete this one (if you can, if not ask a moderator to do it for you in the new question).

Comment: @Learner ... maybe you should ask on meta what's the best way to do it (click the link at the top of the page). Also you're new question could still be formatted much more clearly. using backticks (`) for inline code for example. Have a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see what you can do.

Comment: Can't you use a debugger to inspect pi and pj, or dump them out e.g. `printf("pi = %08x\n", pi);` ? If they are indeed 12 bytes apart then you should edit your question (or re-ask?) about why the stack layout has arranged it so. Maybe check the addresses of &pi and &pj whilst you're at it.

Comment: Please, tell us which compilers and flags you're using to test your program. Also check the [correct output here](http://codepad.org/mShLUWIo).

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to replicate your experience.  With `gcc` on Linux x86:

```
[wally@lenovotower ~]$ cat t.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int *pi,*pj;
    pi=&i;
    pj=&j;

    printf("pi-pj=%d\n",pi-pj);
    return 0;
}

[wally@lenovotower ~]$ gcc -o t t.c
[wally@lenovotower ~]$ ./t
pi-pj=1
[wally@lenovotower ~]$
```

This means that `i` and `j` are adjacent.  Pointer subtraction returns the number of items between the pointers, not the address difference.  To get your result, there would have to be two items-worth of padding in between.  I can't explain how that could be.

Comment: MSVC with no optimisation returns 3: the two items-worth of padding are pi and pj. With optimisation I get -1, i.e. it's arranged i and j the other way around.

Comment: i tried the compilation on Microsoft Visual studio 2010...n output was coming as 3, **@Rup**, can u plz, let me know, how the compiler optimization is changing the output.

Comment: I assume it's because it doesn't need to store p1 and p2 - it just computes them and subtracts them without ever committing them to memory - and so doesn't allocate any space for them on the stack.